# Rounded to 4 decimal places, but output shows 4 decimal places + 4 0s in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers, decimal

I am working on Weather Observation Station 17 in HackerRank.
Query the Western Longitude (LONG_W)where the smallest Northern Latitude (LAT_N) in STATION is greater than 38.7780. Round your answer to 4 decimal places.

Table: STATION
Fields: ID, CITY, STATE, LAT_N, LONG_W
where LAT_N is the northern latitude and LONG_W is the western longitude.

My code:

```
SELECT ROUND(LONG_W,4,0) AS low
FROM STATION
WHERE LAT_N = (SELECT MIN(LAT_N) FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N > 38.7780);
```

Output:
70.13780000
The answer is wrong. I looked up this question online and the code looks the same in other answers. I am using MS SQL Server.
The same code works fine on MySQL

Comment: What is the data type of `LONG_W`? `ROUND` doesn't change the data type of a value; it just *rounds* it.

Comment: LONG_W AND LAT_N are numbers.

Comment: `number` isn't a data type in SQL Server... Is `LONG_W` a `real`, a `float`? A `decimal(27,14)`? A `varchar(20)`? Something else?

Comment: The question mentioned number. LONG_W has 8 decimal points and now it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ROUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function will return the same datatype, precision and scale as the input:

```
select round(1.10045001, 4); -- 1.10050000
select round(1.10055001, 4); -- 1.10060000
```

You need [`CAST(... AS DECIMAL(..., 4))`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to generate a decimal with exactly 4 digits. This function will round the value using same algorithm as `ROUND` during conversion:

```
select cast(1.10045001 as decimal(18, 4)); -- 1.1005
select cast(1.10055001 as decimal(18, 4)); -- 1.1006
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wouldn't use `ROUND`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(12,4), LONG_W) AS low
FROM STATION
WHERE LAT_N = (SELECT MIN(LAT_N) FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N > 38.7780);
```

Also more efficient:

```
SELECT TOP (1) CONVERT(decimal(12,4), LONG_W) AS low
FROM STATION
WHERE LAT_N > 38.7780
ORDER BY LAT_N;
```

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL

```
SELECT CAST(LONG_W AS DECIMAL(10, 4))
FROM STATION
WHERE LAT_N = ( SELECT MIN(LAT_N) FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N > 38.7780);
```

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL SERVER :

SELECT TOP 1 CAST(LONG_W AS DECIMAL(10,4)) FROM STATION
WHERE LAT_N > 38.7780
ORDER BY LAT_N ASC

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT(round(min(LAT_N),4),'F4')
FROM STATION
WHERE LAT_N > 38.7780;


Your Output (stdout)
38.8526
```

Answer (score 0):

actually the question is little bit confusing but still it have some meaning which i understand after getting the right answer.

the condition for LAT_N is confusing, it means that `LAT_N is smallest one and the same time LAT_N is greater than 38.7780`

```
select round(LONG_W,4) from STATION where LAT_N = (SELECT MIN(LAT_N) FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N > 38.7780);
```

`stdout: 70.1378`

Answer (score 0):

This should work. There are several lat_n values greater than 38.7780. However, we want the smallest one of them, and the corresponding long_w. So, to get the smallest lat_n, order the result by lat_n and set the limit to 1. This will pick up the smallest lat_n value.

```
SELECT ROUND(long_w, 4)
FROM station
WHERE lat_n > 38.7780
ORDER BY lat_n
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(LONG_W,4) AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) 
FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N = ( SELECT MIN(LAT_N) FROM STATION WHERE LAT_N > 38.7780);
```

this will work..

Answer (score 0):

My Code works successfully on MYSQL

```
select round (LONG_W,4)
from STATION
where LAT_N>38.7780
order by LAT_N asc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

this the correct answer for this Q in MYSQL

```
select round (LAT_N,4)
from STATION
where LAT_N>38.7780
order by LAT_N asc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for MS SQL - The best way to avoid trailing 0’s after the rounded number- like 452.05 vs 452.050000 is to use the format like `CAST AS DECIMAL`. As for the MS SQL we need to use 'TOP' but in case of MySQL it would be `LIMIT`

```
/*use of CAST function*/
select top 1 cast(long_w as decimal(10,4)) from station
where lat_n > 38.7780 order by lat_n asc
```

the output would be

```
70.1378
```